# mysql single column condition query on a multi-column index

Tags: mysql, sql

suppose a table has only one index : `idx_goods  (is_deleted,price)`
and is_deleted column is either 0 or 1

my query looks like this : `where price < 10`, which of the follwing behavior is this case:
**1** mysql do a full scan on the secondary index for price match
**2** mysql partially scan the secondary index for price match where it starts with `is_deleted=0` in the secondary index, reach `price=10`, then jump to `is_deleted=1` in the secondary index and continue there
**3** mysql ignore the secondary index and scan the base table for price match, **in other words, condition field that's not in the query's index key prefix is not matched against secondary index but against base table, event though the condition field is part of index key**

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN SELECT .... ` and you can see what index is used in query

Comment: there is some incosistency in question. First you wrote about one index, after that about secondary index (maybe secondary field in index) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To utilize index based on multiple fields where condition must mostly use fields from the begining of index. So, if index is on fields (field1, field2, field3) then condition must contain field1.

[More about MySQL index optimisation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimization-indexes.html)

There are some DB systems which can use indexes even if its first part is ommited in condition, but has very limited range of values in it.

Query plan can be checked by using `EXPLAIN SELECT .....` [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html)

For tables with small number of rows (fewer than 10.. from [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table-scan-avoidance.html) ) indexes may be not used, so better prepare more data for real tests.

And as seen in [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4cc1f9119186542dd942b3ab4a78b39e) index is not used for query

```sql
explain select * from test where price < 10
```

but for query below index is used with good results.

```sql
explain select * from test where is_deleted in (0,1) and price < 10
```

If `is_deleted` can be null then condition should be modified to `(is_deleted in (0,1) or is_deleted is null)`, still it uses index.

And, as @Luuk mentioned, in this case (condition only on price field)  index on price will be the best option.

Comment: Also an index on the column `price` alone is favored. see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=caae5668fed28b63e6b32859aa2c49af

Comment: yes, in this specific query. But it looks odd to select rows without considering `is_deleted` field, so main question is, what is the real business case behind this query. So it's always good to know how to check performance of each solution.